# Устройство распознаётся системой, но не показывается lsblk

Tags: linux, администрирование, файловая-система, usb

Есть электронная книга на Android с USB-C разъёмом, которую подключаю к обычному USB порту компьютера. На Windows она распознаётся как *portable composite device* и можно спокойно передавать файлы, однако на Linux ядро распознаёт девайс (вывод `dmesg` ):

> usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
>
> usb 4-1: New USB device found ...

, но не показывает его в `lsblk`, так что не могу замаунтить ФС. При этом книга заряжается через этот кабель. Может в этом проблема? Или надо какой-то пакет поставить?

Comment: попробуйте [android-file-transfer](https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux) или подобные программы работающие через MTP

Comment: @Zt. действительно, поставил `android-file-transfer` для MTP и сразу замаунтилось, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Врятли книга отдаст свою память как флешку. Чаще всего используются протоколы вроде MTP(media transfer protocol) . Создаётся виртуальная файловая система, а за неё отвечает gvfs. Попробуй поставить пакеты связанные с gvfs, mtp, gphoto, fuse.

Comment: Действительно, поставил `android-file-transfer` для MTP и сразу замаунтилось, спасибо

Comment: я через gvfs-mtp и gvfs-gphoto2 подключаюсь. В гноме(и в кедах) папка появляется в проводнике.